# Is $ \mathbb R \cup \{\infty \} \cup \{- \infty\}$ a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $\infty$ and $- \infty$ denote objects neither of which in $\mathbb R$. The sum and product of two numbers is as usual and for $t \in \mathbb R$ define
>
> $$t\infty =
> \begin{cases}
> -\infty,  & \text{if $t < 0$} \\
> 0, & \text{if $t = 0$} \\
> \infty & \text{if $t > 0$}
> \end{cases}$$
>
> $ t + \infty = \infty + t = \infty$ and $t + (-\infty) = (-\infty) + t = (-\infty)$
>
> $\infty + \infty = \infty$ and $(-\infty) + (-\infty) = (-\infty)$ and $\infty + (-\infty) = 0$.

$(-\infty) + (-\infty) = -\infty$ implies  $-\infty = 0$ which doesn't make sense so that the operations on the given vector spaces are contradictory.

Is is correct but missing something else? Is it wrong?

[Here's a capture for context](http://s10.postimg.org/41n54z049/Capture.png)

Comment: That's the way it's defined in my textbook. Everything in the quotes is given.

Comment: $\infty=3\infty-2\infty=\infty-\infty=0$, On the other hand, with different definitions, $\mathbb{R}\cup \infty$ can be a vector space, of course.

Comment: Unless you make the extended real line a field. Is $\infty$ + (-$\infty$) well-defined? Usually it's not a vector space.

Comment: I think the problem might be the rule $\infty + (-\infty) = 0$. It will cause all kinds of trouble in expressions that involve $\infty$ or $-\infty$. Maybe it's better to consider the expression $\infty + (-\infty)$ to be indeterminate, notwithstanding what your book says. Does the book make use of the idea that this expression equals zero?

Comment: @vasya It's given in your textbook *in what context*? Is it asking you the question in the title? Does it suggest that it *is* a vector space?

Comment: http://s10.postimg.org/41n54z049/Capture.png

Comment: This is not even a group, so it is not a vector space.

Comment: OK, so this is (probably) not a definition of a object that you are going to use later in the book; it is just an example of a definition someone could try writing, and you're supposed to discuss whether the "definition" succeeds in defining a vector space. A possible answer might begin, "No, it does not, and here is why ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first line of equalities says it all: if you want to enforce a vector space structure on your extended real line but maintain the intuition of infinity, $t+\infty=\infty$ for any real $t$ implies $t=0$ (in the sense of being the additive identity), which certainly isn't true. Moreover $t\infty=\infty$ for all $t$ also implies $\infty=0$.

Comment: Is $t \neq 0$ because otherwise it would mean $\mathbb R = \{0\}$?